# How to compare what values two models/querysets share in a view for later display in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to compare all the `things` in `ModelOne` with `ModelTwo`, to check which `things` are or are not in one or the other model, then put this in the view context for display in the template.

```
class Things(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class ModelOne(models.Model):
    things = models.ManyToManyField(Things)


class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    things = models.ManyToManyField(Things)
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
one_instance = ModelOne.objects.get(id=one_id)
two_instance = ModelTwo.objects.get(id=two_id)

one_thing_ids = set(one_instance.things.values_list("id", flat=True))
two_thing_ids = set(two_instance.things.values_list("id", flat=True))

shared_thing_ids = one_thing_ids & two_thing_ids
thing_ids_in_one_not_in_two = one_thing_ids - two_thing_ids
thing_ids_in_two_not_in_one = two_thing_ids - one_thing_ids

shared_things = Thing.objects.filter(id__in=shared_thing_ids)
```

You can then pass `shared_things` queryset into the template for display.

If your `Thing` model only has a `name` field and the names are unique we can simplify a little by altering the model:

```py
class Things(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

or even:

```py
class Things(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

(in this case the db table will not have an `id` column, it's not needed)

Either way we can then eliminate the extra Thing query at the end:

```py
one_instance = ModelOne.objects.get(id=one_id)
two_instance = ModelTwo.objects.get(id=two_id)

one_thing_names = set(one_instance.things.values_list("name", flat=True))
two_thing_names = set(two_instance.things.values_list("name", flat=True))

shared_thing_names = one_thing_names & two_thing_names
thing_names_in_one_not_in_two = one_thing_names - two_thing_names
thing_names_in_two_not_in_one = two_thing_names - one_thing_names
```

...and just pass sets of string names into the template.